# Compared to the rest in Baryon Octet, why is neutron decay lifetime so long?

Tags: particle-physics

Compared to the other particles in the baryon octet, neutron decays with a lifetime of about $900s$, compared to $10^{-10}s$ for the rest. Why the discrepancy? Is it because when the neutron decays to the proton, the mass difference is only about $1MeV$, so the phase space is squeezed?

[image]